# Unable to check response size with Rack Deflater

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use Rack::Deflater to compress responses when the body is greater than 512 bytes in size.

Using the example given in the latest [Rack Deflater source code](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/deflater.rb#L25) in my config.ru I get the following error:

> /gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/deflater.rb:20:in `initialize': wrong number
>   of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Any documentation I've found online suggests the syntax I'm using is correct. I'm using RoR 4 and Rack 1.5.5.

This is my config.ru file in its entirety:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require 'rack'

use Rack::Deflater, :if => lambda { |*, body| sum=0; body.each { |i| sum += i.length }; sum > 512 }

run Rails.application
```

I suspect it's some kind of versioning error but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. It's version issue. You paste code from the very last version (`2.0.3`/`2.0.4`), but according to your trace you have 1.5.5 in your local setup.

Here you can see that `Rack::Deflater` doesn't accept any additional options in `1.5.5` -- https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.5/lib/rack/deflater.rb#L20

Firstly options were added in the very next release `1.6.0.beta`. You can see that here -- https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/deflater.rb#L28

Updating your rack should solve your issue for you